# VC++ class fails fresh build, but mysteriously builds after white space added

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build

I have a game project in VC++2010 which I am updating to use SDL, audio first. When I rebuild the project from scratch, the Audio class gives me several linker errors. When I go to Audio.cpp and add some white space anywhere (thus needing to save the file again) and build it compiles successfully. I find this very mysterious. I have restarted Visual Studio a couple times, but this behaviour persists.

I am a novice in C++ programming; most of my experience is with higher-level languages (C#, Python). Thanks for any help.

Here is Audio.h

```
#pragma once

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_thread.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_mixer.h"

#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class AudioTrack {
public:
    string Description;
        string Filename;
        Mix_Music* track;
        AudioTrack(const string& Description, const string& Filename){
                this->Description = Description;
                this->Filename = Filename;
                track = Mix_LoadMUS(Filename.c_str());
        }
};

class AudioEffect {
public:
        string Description;
        string Filename;
        Mix_Chunk* effect;
        AudioEffect(const string& Description, const string& Filename){
                this->Description = Description;
                this->Filename = Filename;
                effect = Mix_LoadWAV(Filename.c_str());
        }
};

class Audio {
private:
        static vector<AudioTrack> tracks;
        static vector<AudioEffect> effects; 

        static void AddTrack(const string& Description, const string& Filename);
        static void AddEffect(const string& Description, const string&  Filename);

public:
        //initializes and loads sound
        static void Init();

        static void Free();

        //plays continuously until there is more music.
        static void PlayTrack(const string& Description);

        //plays once
        static void PlayEffect(const string&  Description);
};
```

Here is Audio.cpp

```
#include "Audio.h"
#include <stdio.h>


//void musicDone() {
//  Mix_HaltMusic();
//  Mix_FreeMusic(music);
//  music = NULL;
//} 

vector<AudioTrack> Audio::tracks;
vector<AudioEffect> Audio::effects;  

void Audio::AddTrack(const string& Description, const string& Filename) {
    AudioTrack newTrack = AudioTrack(Description,Filename);
        tracks.push_back(newTrack);
}

void Audio::AddEffect(const string& Description, const string& Filename) {
        AudioEffect newEffect = AudioEffect(Description,Filename);
        effects.push_back(newEffect);
}  

void Audio::Init() {
        //SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO);

        int audio_rate = 22050;
        Uint16 audio_format = AUDIO_S16; 
        int audio_channels = 2;
        int audio_buffers = 4096;

        if(Mix_OpenAudio(audio_rate, audio_format, audio_channels, audio_buffers)) {
                printf("Unable to open audio!\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        //Descriptions for all tracks and effects
        AddTrack("Title","Title.wav");
        AddTrack("Game","Sample_Track_1_V2.wav");

        AddEffect("Collision","Collision_1.wav");

}

void Audio::Free() {
        //TODO

        //free music


}   

void Audio::PlayTrack(const string& Description) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tracks.size(); i++) {
                if (tracks[i].Description.compare(Description) == 0) {
                        Mix_PlayMusic(tracks[i].track, -1);
                        /*Mix_HookMusicFinished(musicDone);*/
                }
        }
} 

void Audio::PlayEffect(const string& Description) {
        for (int i = 0; i < effects.size(); i++) {
                if (effects[i].Description.compare(Description) == 0) {
                        Mix_PlayChannel(-1,effects[i].effect, 0);
                }
        }
}
```

Here are the linker errors I get on a fresh build:

```
1>Debug\//Audio.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>Draw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl Audio::PlayTrack(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?PlayTrack@Audio@@SAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl setMode(int)" (?setMode@@YAXH@Z)
1>SampleDraft.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl Audio::PlayTrack(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?PlayTrack@Audio@@SAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>SampleDraft.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl Audio::Init(void)" (?Init@Audio@@SAXXZ) referenced in function _SDL_main
1>C:\Dev Code\Sample\Sample 2013 Draft\\Bin\SampleDraft.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

And here are the warnings I get after adding some whitespace to Audio.cpp and simply building. The build is successful and functional:

```
1>Debug\//Audio.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>  SampleDraft.vcxproj -> C:\Dev Code\Sample\Sample 2013 Draft\\Bin\SampleDraft.exe
```

EDIT: This may be completely unrelated. For most of development, in the Solution Explorer header and code files were in separate virtual folders for the purposes of display. However, a couple weeks ago they seemed to switch to be shown all in one folder.

Comment: TL;DR. This is a long shot, but could you check your system date and time to see whether they are correct? This *might* be a possible cause of your problem.

Comment: THANK YOU for posting your found solution. I would have searched forever for this an still wouldn't have found it without your help!

Comment: Oh whoops - looks like I should list that as an actual answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution relates to Visual Studio compiler behaviour! (I originally had this as an editor to my question in 2013, but realized based on @Nevo's comment I should list it as an actual answer.)

Originally, I added the header file `Audio.h` as `Audio.cpp` because of a mis-click in the Add->New Item dialogue. I simply renamed the file and continued coding. However, it appears that Visual Studio stores the type of file in the project file (.vcxproj) as well. Visual Studio was still trying to compile `Audio.h` as code. I fixed this by right-clicking on `Audio.h` in the solution explorer -> General -> Item Type and set it to "C/C++ header" instead of "C/C++ compiler".

The change in the project file looks like so:

```
     <ClCompile Include="Audio.cpp" />
-    <ClCompile Include="Audio.h" />
+    <ClInclude Include="Audio.h" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the first line of your output is trying to give you a warning about the cause:

> 1>Debug//Audio.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than
>   once; extras ignored

The linker is being passed more than one Audio.obj object files, apparently.  It looks like there's a "stale" one in the distribution somewhere (look around with file explorer) that doesn't have the definitions.  When you update and compile the correct Audio.cpp, an Audio.obj is getting created that does have them.

Comment: I checked in all my solution folders for any duplication Audio.obj and could not find one. I made sure I emptied the Recycle Bin. The behaviour persists.

There is only one
    `#include "Audio.h"`
statement in the code, so I do not know why I get LNK4042.

Comment: The linker only cares about .obj files produced by the compiler, but it may be that you have just supplied the same Audio.obj path twice which would be harmless.  You can check the explicit linker options and parameters by right-clicking on your project, and selecting "Properties"-->"Configuration Properties"-->"Linker"-->"Command Line" - I suggest reviewing that (or pasting it into your post if it looks OK to you).

Comment: Ah - I see you found and resolved the problem already - great!

Comment: Thanks! I am satisfied by how odd the problem was.